# Call a function in Compass/SASS

Tags: function, sass

I want to create a function in SASS that generates different classes.
Something like this

```
@function test($class-name) {
    @for $i from 1 through $tot-class {
        .#{$class-name}-#{$i} {
            //some rules
        }
    }
}
```

but i can't figure how to call this function.
I've tried with

```
 @test(red);
```

or

```
 test(red);
```

but it doesn't seem to work.
Which is the right way?

Comment: The error i get is Invalid CSS after "@test": expected selector or at-rule, was "("red");"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The main problem here is that you don't actually want to use a [function](http://sass-lang.com/docs/yardoc/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#function_directives), you want a [mixin](http://sass-lang.com/docs/yardoc/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#mixins). The difference is that functions don't contain any CSS rules - they simply return a value (which you can assign to a variable or use in a CSS property declaration). Mixins, on the other hand, have no return value and can contain full-blown CSS rules to be added when that mixin is included into the SASS document. Here's what your example would look like as a mixin:

```
@mixin test($class-name) {
    @for $i from 1 through $tot-class {
        .#{$class-name}-#{$i} {
            //some rules
        }
    }
}
```

You'd then include the mixin later by using:

```
@include test(red);
```