# SCSS reusable function

Tags: css, function, sass

I have an error in my sass file, I've got no idea what it's not working...

Here's the message I get from calling `.class{ col(6);`

```
error scss/components.scss (Line 18: Invalid CSS after "...gin:7px 0; col": expected "{", was "(6);")
```

Here's the function and variables used to create the function (sorry if it's a bit confusing):

```
$columnWidth:40;
$numberOfColumns:16;
$gutterWidth: 20;

$fullWidth:($columnWidth * $numberOfColumns) +  ($gutterWidth * $numberOfColumns); 

@function perc($target) {
  @return (($target / $fullWidth) * 100%);
}

@function gw($n, $fluid: false) {
  $calculatedValue: ($n * $columnWidth + ($n - 1) * $gutterWidth);
  @if $fluid == false {  
    @return $calculatedValue + px;  
  } @else { 
    @return perc($calculatedValue);
  }
}

@function col($n, $fluid: false){  
  @return unquote("width: gw($n, $fluid);");
}
```

All im trying to do, is re use the `gw()` function, so that I can use it in css to output the number of columns as a width css property, ie `grid(4);` would output `width: 200px;`.

the function gw works because it generates my grid css properly, however I want to define a global function to use everywhere. Hence the `col()` function.

Comment: You forgot to add the code that actually fails. It seems all of those functions work. Addionally, should you not have made `col` a `mixin`? Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/12319330/538866

Comment: I'm calling `.class{ col(6);"` on a class, this is where it's dying. would a mixin work? if it would I'd use it but I'd much rather a function mainly because it's short to add @JonasG.Drange

Comment: A `mixin` will make it easier since you can put SCSS inside it, instead of `unquote` and whatnot. :) But yeah, you would need to have `@include` in front of it.

Answer (score 2):

A mixin is like a function, but does not return anything other than its body, which can be full blown SCSS.

So you can fix this by making `col` a `mixin`, like so:

```
@mixin col($n, $fluid: false){  
  width: gw($n, $fluid);
}
```

Then you can call:

```
.class{ @include col(6) };
```

Which produces:

```
.class {
  width: 340px; }
```

Comment: But if I wanted to do this with a function how could I do it? Thankyou for your answer though

Comment: Since mixins do not return anything, they are replaced by their bodies. A SASS function cannot currently call them/interact with them. So you're kind of stuck with the `@include` keyword. Which is not all bad, since functions should be all logic, no CSS. :)

Answer (score -1):

Functions can only be used to return simple types (string, color, number, etc.) or lists of simple types.  It cannot be used to return a property/value (eg. "color: red"):  all you can ever get when you do this is a string or a list of strings (and strings cannot be used this way).  Mucking around with lists of strings is more work for you than simply *using a mixin*.

```
@function foo() {
    @return color red;
}

.foo {
    $kv: foo();
    #{nth($foo, 1)}: #{nth($foo, 2)}
}
```

Compare to:

```
@mixin foo() {
    color: red;
}

.foo {
    @include foo;
}
```

There's nothing inherently *non-reusable* about your `gw()` function (in fact, it is *more* reusable than the impossible function you're dreaming of):  it returns a numeric value that can be used for *any* property.  In fact, using it in place of a mixin or a function that returns a list of strings is the most efficient way of going about what you're looking for:

```
.foo {
    width: gw(1);
}
```

Comment: The gw function is a main function, I do want to keep the cols function separate as I also want to create another 4 functions from the gw function. Changing the defaluts for each function so it is necessary.  I also want my function to generate the width property as per my example so again it is necessary.

Comment: I'm sorry, the downvote is for what?  The code, as you have it in the OP, is redundant code full of redundancy.  If it isn't showing the full picture, then *you* didn't provide enough code.

Comment: The down vote was because you haven't read the post, I asked, and clearly stated in my question title 'SCSS reusable function'. It seems  you've miss-understood. I clearly wrote throughout my OP that I WANT to re use that function. That's the whole point for this question, it's not `codereview.stackexchange.com/‎`.

Comment: When asking a question, it's expected that the OP have a basic understanding of the subject they're asking about, which you're displaying very little of here.  What you want is *not valid Sass* and probably *never will be*.  My updated answer contains your *only* options on this subject.

Comment: Which is exactly why people come here is it not? to find out if they're doing the right thing. Actually my other option which I already knew about which @jonas provided above your answer which is also better than your answers. How am I displaying 'very litte' understanding of the subject, I clearly know enough of sass to create the functions to begin with. You're ridiculous.